# Menus behave differently on iPad in portrait and landscape orientations

Tags: ipad, hover, orientation, touch-event

I have a menu that uses a CSS hover to reveal the sub menu items. It works perfectly on a computer, and I've added a hack that makes the hover work on the iPad, too - I can just use the :active state.

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
```

CSS:

```
.nav ul ul{
    height:0;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul, 
.nav ul li:active ul{
    height:auto;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

However, it behaves differently in portrait and landscape orientations on the iPad. It works fine in landscape, but in portrait, or when zoomed in, the sub-menu flashes up and then disappears immediately.

I've created a JSFiddle to try to demonstrate. It has some rather strange behaviour that, in landscape, clicking on the menu actually navigates to Twitter, even though there's no link to Twitter in the code?! Within my website, in landscape, clicking the menu works as expected. But even though it doesn't work as well as within my actual application, you can still see that there's a big difference between the two orientations. In portrait, it flicks on and off as I get in my application.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdEKL/4/

I've searched to find out why there should be a difference between how the code is interpreted in the different orientations (and when zoomed in), but can't find any information.